# Removing mongo entry after a specific set of time in a Meteor application

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have a database of time sensitive data. Is there a "best practice" to delete an entry after x time? Probably 30 minutes but maybe 24 hours. I've thought about intervals and stuff but that seems like a lazy solution that would eat resources quickly.

Comment: Have you considered filtering the data when you retrieve it instead of actually deleting it?

Comment: I have, but odds are with the amount of data, it'll get messy fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intervals are the correct solution. However, to not eat up resources, as well as to be safe against server restart, do not create a new interval for each element you want to remove. Instead, run one global interval that will clear all the elements in a given period:

```
var clear = function() {
  var min = new Date(new Date() - DURATION);
  Documents.remove({
    createdAt: {$lt: min}
  });
};


Meteor.startup(function() {
  clear();
  Meteor.setInterval(clear, INTERVAL);
});
```

Where `DURATION` is the minimal number of miliseconds a document should stay in the DB, and `INTERVAL` is how often you would like to perform the purge.

Comment: what is Meteor in reference to? Do I need to have this dependency in order for this to work? Thanks! This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @AlexanderGriffin: I think I don't understand your question. The code sample use Meteor APIs, but method I described will of course work in any environment.